# How can I retrieve data from Telegram.WebApp.sendData() using telegraf.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, telegram-bot, telegraf

I use telegraf.js
can't get data from Telegram.WebApp.sendData()

```
bot.start(async(ctx)=>{

        ctx.reply('Hello', {
            reply_markup:{
                inline_keyboard: [
                    [{text: 'Auth', web_app:{url:FRONT_URL}}]
                ]
            }
        })
}
```

my front-end app

```
window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData(JSON.stringify({data:'test'}))
```

I try methods like this,

```
bot.on('message', (ctx)=>{})
bot.on('web_app_data', (ctx)=>{})
```

events are not processed
I read the telegraf documentation and did not find examples of working with webApp

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to implement this on telegraf at all?

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me

```
bot.on('message', (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply('Received action');
});
```